# how to display output in the following format in unix

Tags: unix, awk

Hi my data looks in the below format in unix file

BENEFITS-T_FACT_DEPNDT_COVRG-230

BENEFITS-T_FACT_DEPNDT_COVRG-290

BENEFITS-T_FACT_ELECTN-0

BENEFITS-T_FACT_ELECTN-39092

HR-T_DIM_CLNT-0

HR-T_DIM_CLNT-98

HR-T_DIM_CMPNY-10

HR-T_DIM_CMPNY-45

I need to display the output like this:

domain -tablename- before load cnt: 230 after load cnt :290

ex : BENEFITS - T_FACT_DEPNDT_COVRG -before load cnt: 230 after load cnt :290

```
 HR -T_DIM_CLNT -before load cnt: 0 after load cnt :98
```

Can someone please suggest an answer in unix ???

Comment: It would be very nice if you reformat your question so that we actually know what is going on. At the moment it is ver hard to read and to understand what you want.

Comment: More than "very nice", this question is basically unanswerable in its current form. Sairam, if you have a programming question, please add the code you're having trouble with. Check [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips. If what you're looking for is a handout, someone to write something to meet your formatting requirements, then this isn't the place for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this enough?

```
awk -F  "-" '{if(NR%2){printf $1 " " $2 " -before load cnt: " $3}else{printf " after load cnt: " $3 "\n"}}' filename
```